# Change DataGridView background color depending on condition

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataSource for my `DataGridView` is an array of `Item` objects:

```
public class Item
{
    public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
    public bool IsValid {get; set;}
}

var items = new Item []{ /* items */ };
dgv.DataSource = items;
```

If I would like to control the `BackgroundColor` of each row in `dgv` depending on the value of `Item.IsValid` property, how can I do that?

Loop-through-dgv-rows based solution is not acceptable.

Comment: Google "c# winforms datagridview cellformatting".

Comment: Is it WinForms or WPF?